# Excel Determine Ascending Rank Based on Each Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the raw data:

```
Date      Name  Score
25/2/2021   A   10
25/2/2021   B   8
25/2/2021   C   8
25/2/2021   D   4
25/2/2021   E   1
24/2/2021   A   0
24/2/2021   B   20
24/2/2021   C   7
24/2/2021   D   10
24/2/2021   E   4
```

I would love to assign consecutive rank (preferably ascending order) to the students by each date, as follows:

```
Date    Name    Score   Rank
25/2/2021   A   10      1
25/2/2021   B   8       2
25/2/2021   C   8       2
25/2/2021   D   4       3
25/2/2021   E   1       4
24/2/2021   A   0       5
24/2/2021   B   20      1
24/2/2021   C   7       3
24/2/2021   D   10      2
24/2/2021   E   6       4
```

I've tried customised rank function but it's hard to output this result, how could I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In `D2` use:

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$11,A2,C$2:C$11,">"&C2)+1
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, try:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(C$2:C$11,A$2:A$11=A2))>C2))+1
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! 

However, I wanna get a consecutive rank for this scenario, I've amended the issue in the question, could u help me again?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below formula with `Excel365`. It will also work on unsorted data.

```
=XMATCH(C2,SORT(FILTER($C$2:$C$11,$A$2:$A$11=A2),1,-1))
```

[image]

Comment: What a great idea! However, I found there will be duplicated rank if the score is 0, and I wanna get a consecutive rank.

I've added the scenario in the question, it is appreciated if u could help me again~